# Macro error at Workbook_Open() but run normally after

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

My code produce an `Error 32809 Application-defined or object-defined error` at line `Sheets("Data Entry").Unprotect sheetPassword` if it runs when the workbook open in `Workbook_Open()`. However, that error is not produced when run by pressing F5 in the `Workbook_Open()` sub. This is an data entry workbook so I much prefer it runs automatically, rather than someone going into the code and press F5 every time opening the workbook.
I have tried

- Copying into a new sheet, renamed it "Data Entry"
- Let the workbook sleep 3 seconds while `DoEvents` (so it can load whatever elements it needs)

The code before the error is as follow

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.EnableEvents = False
currentMac = GetMACAddress
Dim ans As Integer
Dim isReviewer As Boolean
If InStr(designerMac, currentMac) > 0 Then
    ans = MsgBox("Designers mac detected, turn on dev mode?", vbYesNo, "Developer mode")
    isDevMode = ans = vbYes
End If
If isAfterDueDate Then 'offline check
    promtRowUnicode = 42
    titleRowUnicode = 30
    MsgBoxUni promtRowUnicode, vbOKOnly, titleRowUnicode
    CleanUpAfterJob
End If

ThisWorkbook.Unprotect workbookPass
Sheets("Data Entry").Unprotect sheetPassword 'Error 32809 here
Sheets("_Properties").Unprotect sheetPassword
'Some more code'
End sub
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: *Error 32809* is not meaningful. What is the **complete, exact** error message that you're getting? Excel does not output just an error number. You have the complete error right on the screen in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. You're asking us for help solving your problem - it's in your best interest to provide all of the information you have available to make it as easy as possible for us to give you that help.

Comment: You might have to try one of the many suggestions you get when you Google this error.  Lots of reasons that I could see and many of them point to some sort of corruption.

Comment: @KenWhite I updated the details of the error.

Comment: @ACCtionMan Because everything runs normally when started manually, I think it might not be corrupted.

Comment: Easy way to rule that out would be to try the same line of code and password protection etc. in a brand new workbook.

Comment: @ACCtionMan if I test the way you want, it would only confirm that Excel has a problem or not. And I did, it doesn't produce any error.

Comment: `Sheets("Data Entry")` refers to the `ActiveWorkbook`, which may not be `ThisWorkbook` when the `Workbook_Open` code runs.  Try changing to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Entry").Unprotect ...`

Comment: @chrisneilsen I tried adding `ThisWorkbook.` , it's still the same. I predicted that it should because there are many times I ran the workbook alone, without any other workbooks open.

Comment: So you created a new workbook and didn't get the error. That confirms it's most likely your workbook is corrupted like I said before.